# When is $\{e\}=\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b,c\rangle$

Tags: cyclic-groups, roots-of-unity

Let $G=(\mathbb{Z}/540\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong C_2 \times C_{18} \times C_4 $.

Find elements in $G$ so that $ord(a)=2$, $ord(b)=18$, $ord(c)=4$ and $\{e\}=\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b,c\rangle = \langle b\rangle \cap \langle a,c\rangle = \langle c\rangle \cap \langle a,b\rangle$

---

The first part is easy but is there also an easy way to check if the intersection is trivial? What properties must $a,b,c$ have for that to happen?

My approach was to pick $a=161$, $b=11$, $c=107$. Then $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle \cap \langle c \rangle = \{e\}$ and they have the order I want.

Then I have 3 cases to check. The easiest is

$\{1\}=\langle 11\rangle \cap \langle 161,107\rangle \Rightarrow \{1,11,11^2,...,11^{17}\}\cap\{1,161,107,107^2,107^3,161\cdot107,161\cdot107^2,...\}\overset{!}{=}\{1\}$

I know that $11$ is prime and the numbers in the second set must have a prime factorization of $(7\cdot 23)^x\cdot 107^y, x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$. But this doesn't guarantee anything, since the remainder can still be divisible by $11$.

So I'd like to have some advice how I can proceed from here.

Comment: I would think it should be easier to work in the product of cyclic groups, rather than the unit group directly.

Comment: @Arthur Could you maybe give me more context to why that is useful? Do you mean that I should look at $C_2 \times C_4 \times C_{18}$ But since $2,4,18$ are not coprime, $\langle a,b\rangle$ etc. isn't cyclic if I understand that correctly.

Comment: I just mean, looking for elements of order 2 and of order 18 and of order 4, and checking whether groups have trivial intersections seems a lot easier in $C_2\times C_{18}\times C_4$ than it does in $(\Bbb Z/540\Bbb Z)^\times$. I have no idea what the order of $161\in (\Bbb Z/540\Bbb Z)^\times$ is, or what $\langle 161\rangle\cap\langle11, 107\rangle$ is. But I can tell you immediately that $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ have orders 2, 18 and 4 respectively, and $\langle(1,0,0)\rangle$ and $\langle(0,1,0), (0,0,1)\rangle$ intersect only at the identity.

Comment: @Arthur True, I get that. But to what number in $G$ does $(1,0,0)$ etc. translate to?

Comment: That's a job for the theorem that lets you say $(\mathbb{Z}/540\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong C_2 \times C_{18} \times C_4$ in the first place. Or, since you already have that isomorphism written down, I would have personally accepted elements described from either group (unless you were explicitly asked to give elements from $(\mathbb{Z}/540\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$).

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for your help, I think I got it now. But I've one question about your notation. I get why you write $(1,0,0)$ and so on but how can I describe $0$? As an element that only "maps" to itself or better said an element that stays the same when doing $0^2, 0^3,...$

Comment: I usually think of cyclic groups additively. So when I say $(0,0,0)$ in the product of cyclic groups, that corresponds to $1$ in the group of units modulo 540. The symbol $0$ has no place in a multiplicative group.

Comment: @Arthur great, thanks for your help.